# Подписывание сборок в .NET

Tags: .net, dll, библиотеки, цифровая-подпись, assembly

Имеется решение, которое включает в себя несколько проектов (несколько проектов библиотек классов и один проект веб-приложение). Исходя из этого появился вопрос: необходимо ли подписывать проекты, которые имеют тип "Библиотека классов", строгим именем?

Для подписания использую стандартные средства Visual Studio, которые создают файл `*.snk`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]